# Critical Exponents for Island Mainland Transition (Percolation Theory)

Tags: graph-theory, statistical-physics, percolation

I was looking at this paper [“Islands in Sea” and “Lakes in Mainland” phases and related transitions simulated on a square lattice](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view?usp=sharing) on Percolation theory. The concept of phase transition used here seems to be a bit different compared to the more popular bond percolation or site percolation based models of phase transition. Now, normally for phase transitions [critical exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent) exist. I wonder if we consider the probability $p$ analogous to temperature, there is some physical quantity $f$, which can be expressed in terms of a power law close to $p_{c1}$ and $p_{c2}$.

In the paper they do show that $(d\chi/dp)^{-1}$ vs. $|p-p_{c1}|$ or $(d\chi/dp)^{-1}$ vs. $|p-p_{c2}|$, follows *sort of* a power law. But it doesn't seem to follow the power law exactly. And secondly $\chi$ isn't a very *physical* quantity so as to speak. It would be more interesting if something like correlation length followed a power law.

> **So, my question is basically:**
>
> Has there been any research based on a similar model of phase
>   transition, which shows existence of a critical exponent other than
>   the one shown in this paper (i.e. $(d\chi/dp)^{-1}$ vs. $|p-p_{c1}|$
>   or $(d\chi/dp)^{-1}$ vs. $|p-p_{c2}|$) for the infinite system case (for a $N\times N$ system where $N\to\infty$)? Also, I'd be interested if someone on MathOverflow could suggest a $f$ which might possibly follow a power law during phase transition, or prove their existence.

Edit 1: As requested in the comments I'm adding the definitions of the variables used in the question.

- $\chi(p)$ has been defined as $N_B(p)-N_W(p)$ where $N_B(p)$ and $N_W(p)$ are the number of black clusters and white clusters respectively at a probability $p$. Although it is called "Euler's number" I doubt it is a true invariant (which is a requirement in mathematical topology).
- $p_{c1}$ is the probability $p$, when transition from $N_W=1$ to $N_W>1$ occurs (white background *breaks*).
- $p_{c_2}$ is the probability $p$, when transition from $N_B>1$ to $N_B=1$ occurs.

Edit 2: It has been mentioned in the comments that the notion of critical exponents does not exist for finite system size as has been dealt with in the paper. My question is regarding the **infinite system size equivalent** of the case dealt with in the paper.

Edit 3: **Please note** that I'm not interested in spanning cluster percolation which is the usual percolation much spoken about. I'm interested in a different type of percolation i.e. when $N_B$ becomes $1$ and $MP \to LM$ occurs as has been discussed in the paper I linked in the first line. Please don't refer to the [similar looking paper on ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04522) which isn't the same. It is talking about the general spanning cluster percolation which I'm not interested in.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by $\chi$, $p_{c1}$ or $p_{c2}$ (you might include the definition of these so people looking at your question don't have to look at the papers).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Added the definitions!

Comment: the "Island-Mainland" transition from [arXiv:1612.04522](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04522) is actually a crossover, rather than a phase transition, without a diverging correlation length; this seems to preclude the notion of a critical exponent; in an infinite system the transition becomes the usual percolation transition, and then you know the critical exponents, but not for the finite system.

Comment: I don't think it is equivalent to the usual percolation transition which involves formation of a spanning black cluster. The percolation I'm interested is when $N_B$ becomes $1$ and it starts to look like white lakes in a black mainland. And that is what $p_{c2}$ represents in [the paper I linked](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view). It seems you have been reading the [**wrong** paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04522) which is talking about **spanning cluster** percolation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem considered in the [Island-Mainland paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04522) is site-percolation on a two-dimensional square lattice, with one modification of the conventional problem: two squares of the same colour are considered connected if they are nearest-neighbor (they share an edge) or next-nearest-neighbor (they share a vertex). This modification has no effect on the percolation transition, see [arXiv:cond-mat/0408338](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0408338.pdf)  and [arXiv:cond-mat/0609635](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0609635): the critical concentration $p_c=0.592746$ is the same whether we only consider nearest-neighbors or include next-nearest-neighbors in a connected cluster.

So the "mixed phase" in the Island-Mainland paper, where neither the black nor white squares are fully connected, occurs for concentrations $p$ in the interval $(0.41,0.59)$. This is for an infinite lattice. The cited paper studies this numerically for a $50\times 50$ lattice, and finds for the mixed phase an interval $(0.39,0.61)$, which is already quite close to the infinite-lattice limit.

Concerning power law scaling and critical exponents, see [arXiv:cond-mat/0304024](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0304024), where the "wrapping probability" $R_L$ for site percolation on an $L\times L$ square lattice with periodic boundary conditions was calculated. (This is the probability that a cluster grows large enough to wrap around in the horizontal direction.) The derivative $dR_L/dp$ at the critical concentration scales as
$$\frac{dR_L}{dp}\propto L^{1/\nu}$$
with critical exponent $\nu=4/3$. This is expected to be a universal result, the same for nearest-neighbor and next-nearest-neighbor connectivity, so it should apply to the Island-Mainland paper.

The plot below, from arXiv:cond-mat/0304024, shows the power law scaling of $dR_L/dp$ fitted to $\nu=1.334$ for the square lattice. (The exponent is different for a hexagonal lattice.)
[image]

Comment: "wrapping around a specific axis" just means that the connected cluster extends either from $x=0$ to $x=L$ (horizontal axis, denoted by $R_L^h$ in the paper) or from $y=0$ to $y=L$ (vertical axis, denoted by $R_L^v$); for a square lattice these wrapping probabilities are the same, but for other lattices they may differ.

Comment: Thanks for that definition. On re-reading your answer I have some confusions. You state $p_c=0.592746$ is the critical concentration (which is same whether we consider nearest neighbors or next nearest neighbors). BUT, [in the paper I mentioned](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view) there are two critical probabilities $p_{c1}=0.13 \pm 0.005$ and $p_{c2}=0.87 \pm 0.005$.

Comment: According to their convention, $p_{c2}$ is actually the probability when the system percolates (MP $\to$ LM) i.e. a giant connected black cluster is formed such that $N_B=1$ (and not just a black **spanning** cluster which you seem to talk about at $p_c=0.592746$). BTW [the paper you read](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view) and [the paper I linked](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view) are not the same.

Comment: So basically, I don't find the value of $0.87 \pm 0.005$ anywhere on the net for a square infinite lattice. It's not on Wikipedia's [Percolation Threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold) page. In short your claim that the [Island Mainland paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onBqzq50ApMzyvgMYekvjXdUXRbuhoZN/view) is just a "modification of conventional percolation problem" doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Given that the bounty period is going to expire soon, would you please kindly reply to my query?

Comment: There is not much I can add to my answer: you asked for power law scaling and critical exponents, and for that you need a diverging correlation length. In a 2D square lattice there are only two critical concentrations at which the correlation length diverges: $p_c=0.59$ and $p'_c=1-p_c=0.41$. There is no diverging correlation length at the other values $p_{c1}=0.87$ and $p_{c2}=1-p_{c1}=0.13$, so there can be no power law scaling and no critical exponents at those concentrations. So if  it is power law scaling you want, you'll need to work at $p_c$ or $p'_c$, not at $p_{c1}$ or $p_{c2}$.

Comment: Do you have any source which explains why "diverging correlation length" is a necessity for existence of critical exponents or power scaling law? Or could you explain it?

Comment: oh this is simply because if the correlation length is finite, say some finite value $\xi$, then system is not scale invariant; it will look differently on length scales smaller than $\xi$ than on length scales larger than $\xi$; and by definition power laws are scale invariant, see for example this [explanation](http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/~allen/540-05/scaling.html)